# Ajax calls fail on iPhone if device screen is turned off

Tags: javascript, iphone, ajax, web

We are facing an issue with iOS development where we repeatedly poll our servers with AJAX calls and those calls stop being made once the screen is turned off.

Which is fine, I initially was able to accept the fact that when the screen was turned off, the iPhone would turn off the radio connection, but that is not what is happening.  If you were downloading something (even from our website) it would continue to download.  Furthermore, if the AJAX calls resumed once the screen was turned back on, it wouldn't be a major issue but the AJAX calls stop happening (no server logs exist for after when the iPhone is turned back on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you polling? setinterval instead of settimeout seems to stick better.